# clearing redirect cache from a different location for Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching

How do you tell the Chrome Browser to not use the cached version of your site when it is redirected from a different location?

We have site www.example.com which has the normal cache busting techniques meta tags and adding ?a=b in your file and http calls however.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
<script src="src/app.js?v=3.21.54"></script>
```

You update your code and all the customers get the new not the old, this works great!

Then SharePoint happened...

Your company got SharePoint which has a link to your site www.example.com but you found something odd happening Chrome uses cache when it is being redirected. Now with your bustfu failing what does one do?